# Collecting two separate column results from mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database tables containing similar data - one is the amount of work completed by a process, the other is the amount of errors made by that process.

I would like to display the percentage of right first time work.

My query for counting the number of items by process is:

```
SELECT Counter.Process, count( Counter.Process ) AS count
                            FROM Counter WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
                            GROUP BY Counter.Process
                            ORDER BY count DESC
```

The above gives me a list similar to:

```
Process    | count
-------------------
Process A  | 40
Process B  | 32
Process C  | 102
Process D  | 23
```

I have a second table with the same fields in it for recording errors, called 'Errors'.

By using the same query (but changing the table names obviously) I can get a list of processes and errors.

What I want to do is create a PHP web page showing the percentage of errors per process.

My problem is if I create the two queries separately, when I loop through them using a PHP Where loop I don't know how to make the calculation to show the percentage.

I tried using a UNION between the two SQL queries, but I can't get it to show the two different count readings against the process.

Ideally, I'd like a way to show the data like this:

```
Process   | Counter.count | Errors.count
Process A     40              2
Process B     32              0
Process C     102             18
Process D     23              8
```

I would really appreciate any advice/suggestions as to how I can accomplish this - if you need more info on my database tables, please let me know

Thanks for reading

S

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use a sub-query:

```
SELECT Counter.Process, count( Counter.Process ) AS Count,
      (SELECT count(Errors.Process) 
         FROM Errors
        WHERE Process=Counter.Process 
          AND (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')) AS Errors
                            FROM Counter WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
                            GROUP BY Counter.Process
                            ORDER BY count DESC
```

Regards,
Neil.

Comment: No, he should JOIN the two tables, using an inner join, and get the resultset he needs.

Comment: From what I can see Neil, your suggestion does exactly what I need. Truth, can you explain what Join would offer that Neils solution doesn't? Thanks both for your help!

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the query. if you have indexes on process column, it is also pretty good. otherwise, the join solution might be better. to make the count without indexes would require full table scan on the errors table for every row returned in the group by on the first table. in that case, the join solution might be better as each table is scanned only once. if the data in the table is not big, then the query is ok even without indexes.

Comment: @truth you can't join the tables. you need to left join the results of running the two queries seperately.

Comment: I've tried Neils code, and it works for me (thanks again!) - only thing I can't seem to do is get the results in DESC order, even though it's in the query to do so. The results don't seem to be in any particular order, though if I change if from DESC to ASC they do change - neither are how they should be. If you can tell me if ordering the results of this query is possible, I'd appreciate it, otherwise I'm still happy as it gives me the data I need.

Comment: I agree with A.J. - I should have added in my submission 'You could use a sub-query if the tables are fairly small'.  For best performance use A.Js join and index (Process,Time) on both tables.

Comment: ooh hold on, it's ordering correctly in Sequel Pro, but not on the PHP page. Odd...

Comment: @neil or he can just add an index if it does not exist and stay with your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not run it so there might be mistakes. you can make the two selects, and left join the results:

```
select s.process, s.success_count, e.error_count
from 
(SELECT Counter.Process as process, count( Counter.Process ) AS success_count
 FROM Counter
 WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
 GROUP BY Counter.Process
) s left join
(SELECT Errors.Process, count( Errors.Process ) AS error_count
      FROM Errors
      WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
      GROUP BY Errors.Process 
) e
on (s.Process = e.process)
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to run situations like this through PHP as it confuses me less, so I will explain how I think I would do it in PHP (I say 'think' because I might not know something about your database structure or system specifications that would make me thing otherwise):

```
$rows = array();
$res = mysql_query('SELECT Counter.Process, count( Counter.Process ) AS count
                        FROM Counter WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
                        GROUP BY Counter.Process
                        ORDER BY count DESC');
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
    $rows[] = $arr;
}

$res2 = mysql_query('SELECT Errors.Process, count( Errors.Process ) AS count
                        FROM Counter WHERE (TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59')
                        GROUP BY Errors.Process
                        ORDER BY count DESC');
while ($arr2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<count($rows); $i++)
    {
        if ($arr2["Process"] == $data[$i]["process"])
        {
            break;
        }
        //Do your functions with $arr and $data[$i] at this point...
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it in PHP is fine, but database servers are built specifically for handling these situations in the most efficient way possible. Also, you'll be transferring around a lot less data so it will be quicker in that respect too.

Answer (score 0):

Doing it without a subquery should be simple:

```
SELECT 
    Counter.Process
    , COUNT(Counter.Process) AS ProcessCount
    , COUNT(Errors.Process) AS ProcessErrors
FROM
    Counter
    LEFT JOIN
    Errors
    ON Counter.Process = Errors.Process
WHERE
    Counter.TIME BETWEEN '2012-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-07-06 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
    Counter.Process
```

You can do an explain on both queries to see which is the best for your data.

-edit: I've changed it to a LEFT JOIN so you don't miss rows if a process has no errors.

Comment: what will happen if first table has 4 rows and second has two ? after the join you will have 8 rows and grouping by that will give the count of 8.